# Pull/Push files from/to the Emulator

Tags: android

I want to try Pull/Push files from/to the Emulator, hence I found some tutorial about that but when I go to file explorer in DDMS view, the push/pull button is DISABLED...WHY ??

Comment: Did you select the file you want to pull or select the directory you want to push to? If nothing is selected in the file explorer then the buttons are disabled

Comment: Yes, I got it. What if the file is inserted into the emulator,will it remain there or will be flushed as the emulator shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the "USB debugging" option in the emulator first and then open the Android Device Monitor --> DDMS perspective --> Select the emulator. You should be able to see the options enabled when you select a file or folder from file explorer.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hWcS.png)